# Count number of cases

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `Leaves` which has `Employee ID`, `Leave Type` and `Date`. For example, If an employee with ID = 1234 applies for a sick leave from 1-June-2014 to 5-June-2014, this will be stored in Leave tables day by day, means that the following records will be added:
1234    sick leave    1-June-2014
1234    sick leave    2-June-2014
1234    sick leave    3-June-2014
1234    sick leave    4-June-2014
1234    sick leave    5-June-2014
This is considered as one case. To clarify what I mean by the case: The total cases is how many leave request had been applied… for example:
[image]
What I need is to get the following information by SQL statement (I should determine a period: 1-January-2014 to 30-December-2014, for example):

Sick leave cases: 2

Escort leave cases: 2

Study leave cases: 1

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is a bit strange, because of these daily rows, if the same person will have several escort leaves, then you have to figure out different cases.

For this certain case you can use something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*), leavetype 
FROM (
  SELECT leavetype
  FROM Leaves
  GROUP BY employee_id, leavetype
)
GROUP BY leavetype;
```

My suggestion is to use case_start and case_end dates for one case row.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
select leave_type, count(*)
from (
  select employee_id, leave_type
  from leaves
  where date between ...
  group by employee_id, leave_type) t
group by leave_type;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select LeaveType, count(EmployeeID) as TotalCases from(
select EmployeeID, LeaveType, count(LeaveType) as count_LeaveType 
from Leaves 
where Date BETWEEN '2007-02-01' AND '2007-02-31'; 
group by EmployeeID, LeaveType) as A
group by LeaveType, A.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the `SQLFiddle` below.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58fd8/24)

```
SELECT leave_type,COUNT(leave_type) FROM
(SELECT leave_type,count(leave_type)
FROM leaves 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY leave_type,emp_id) t
GROUP BY leave_type
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I am still not sure if your answer considers the following: A case is counted for a successive group of dates (with same ID & class) and also is counted per each "ID,Type & Date" if there is no "ID,Type & Date+1","ID,Type & Date+2" ... etc ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: if the same person will have several sick leaves, then I have to figure out different cases. I think your solution doesn't consider that, see your example after I added new record (new case) at the last: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45b62/1

Comment: From your question I understood count(leaveType) group by empID. Check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e603e5/1

Comment: Consider the last record (in your last link) to be with the ID=1234, then sick leave cases should be 3, but by your result is still 2.

Comment: The same ID could have several type of leave see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bf81/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56399/discussion-between-ullas-and-aan).

Answer (score 0):

I am no sure how this will be done in `PostgreSQL` but in `MySQL` it can be achieve by following command :

**QUERY**

```
SELECT  Leave type, count(Leave type) 
FROM Leave 
WHERE (Date BETWEEN  '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-30' ) 
GROUP BY Leave type
```

Comment: This one is not the right solution for the question

Comment: That will group all the days of one type together as a single result line; not what the OP wants.